# Speed up iPhone SMS app

Tags: iphone

I found that after some weeks of usage, my SMS app on a iPhone 3G (iOS 3.0.1, JB) seems to take a few more seconds to start than usual.

On all other cellphones I had, you had to delete old messages because of memory constrains and to make the app work better. Does this apply to the iPhone as well?

If so, how can I delete all messages of all contacts that are more than 1 month old, or something?

As the SMS database is SQLite based, I could script it. I even found this [link](http://blog.eugeneoden.com/2008/07/28/script-to-delete-all-iphone-sms-messages/) regarding this but has been hesitating to use it.

How do you do it?

Comment: Are you jailbroken? I've played around in the AddressBook database file. There seems to be no rhyme or reason to its "organization" though. If you're still interested, I could look up the location of the database in the filesystem. I'm not sure how to speed up the SMS app though. Sounds like a fun project though. I wouldn't mind experimenting with my 3G as well.

Comment: What version of the iOS are you currently running?

Comment: The SMS database seems to be located at /var/mobile/Library/SMS/sms.db. You think deleting old records from it will speed up the SMS app? Am I the only one feeling it slow to launch?

I'm running a JB iPhone 3G, iOS 3.0.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not for the faint of heart, but I've done some research into iPhone daemons, and deleting/ disabling certain ones can have an impact on speed. [Here's](http://thebigboss.org/2008/11/09/iphone-slower-than-before) a lesson from BigBoss about the subject. [Here's](http://www.ipodtouchfans.com/forums/showthread.php?t=224341) a list of daemons and what they do (I found this really helpful).

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I cannot remember where I read this, but turning off Spotlight search indexing for messages should speed it up. Go into Settings: General: Spotlight Search, and uncheck Messages.